# Impossible to connect spark to mongoDB atlas: RuntimeError: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number

Tags: python, mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark, pymongo

I am trying to connect my atlas mongodb cluster via pyspark session from a windows 11 machine where is installed and running Spark. I already read many sources over internet without any successful results. I already set JAVA, SPARK home on windows and downloaded missing jar files to put into jars folder. I can connect on same mongodb cluster via pymongo library, but no chance via spark session by using pyspark.
Below my code run on vscode and error:

```
import pyspark
import os
import findspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkConf

os.environ["JAVA_HOME"] = "C:/java/jdk/"
os.environ["SPARK_HOME"] = "C:/spark/"
os.environ["PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS"] = "--master local[3] pyspark-shell"
os.environ["PYSPARK_HOME"] = "C:/Users/Alessandro/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python.exe"
os.environ["PATH"] += ";C:/spark/bin/;C:/java/jdk/bin"

findspark.init()
mongo_uri_ar = "mongodb+srv://user:password@emacluster.9hhrekg.mongodb.net/"
mongo_db_ar = "hadoop"
mongo_db = mongo_uri_ar + mongo_db_ar
mongoParam = "?authSource=admin&readPreference=primary&connectTimeoutMS=60000&w=majority"
input_uri = mongo_db + mongoParam


spark_ar = SparkSession.builder \
    .master("local[*]") \
    .appName("MySparkAR") \
    .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", input_uri) \
    .config("spark.mongodb.output.uri", input_uri) \
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.12:3.0.2") \
    .enableHiveSupport() \
    .getOrCreate()

sc_ar = spark_ar.sparkContext
sql_ar = spark_ar.sql

spark_ar.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled", "true")
spark_ar.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.fallback.enabled", "true")
spark_ar.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.selfDestruct.enabled","true")
```

RuntimeError: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number
Please someone can help me out, because I tried anything.
Thanks in advance.